# how to calculate area of polygon in ggradar

Tags: r, radar-chart, spider-chart

I'm hoping to calculate the area of a polygon using ggradar.

From the research I've done so far, I think the goal is to calculate the area of each triangle and add them all together. Since we know the distance from the centroid to each point and the angle between the two sides of each triangle, we can calculate the area for each wedge using side1 x side2 x sin(pi/n)/2 (where n = number of variables, in this case 4) and adding all the wedges together.

Using mtcars data as an example:

```
mtcars_radar <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "group") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group), rescale) %>% 
  tail(1) %>% 
  select(1:5)

ggradar(mtcars_radar)+
  theme(legend.position='right')
```

[radar chart using mtcars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mfZK.png)

So then my issue is how to automatically calculate the area of each triangle and add them together. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've got to ask why would you want to do this? The total area would vary depending on the order of the variables around the radar. Is that something that's desirable for your statistic? That seems pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes the area depends on the order of the variables. However, if the order of the variables are kept the same, you could compare the area of two polygons to say car1 is better or worse than car2 based on whatever criteria you set. I'm not planning on comparing cars, just an example.

Comment: Why don't you just sum the magnitude of the values? What does measuring the area add?

Comment: But what if one "car" is better than the other on adjacent categories and bad in the others, while the second one is good in two opposite strengths (opposite in the chart)? Then, although both of them have merit, the first one will have a far greater area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I question the utility, it certainly is possible to do this in R. Here's such a function

```
radar_area <- function(data) {
  vals <- data[, -1, drop=FALSE] # assume the first column is the ID
  first <- 1:ncol(vals)
  second <- c(first[-1], first[1])
  Reduce(`+`, Map(function(i, j) vals[,i] * vals[,j], first, second))/2 * sin(2*pi/ncol(vals))
}

radar_area(mtcars_radar)
```

We pair up all ends of the triangles, and then we multiple them, then add and adjust according to the angle between them. This assumes the center of the circle is at 0,0 but in the sample plot provided it appears the radar plot does not put 0 in the exact center of the image. There seems to be an offset. If necessary, you could add the length of that offset to the triangle lengths.

Comment: This works, so thank you. However I'd like to clarify that I was asking for help with my code, not for an opinion on whether or not my code was "useful".